# Internet Connectivity of my Java App

Tags: java, network-programming

I am programming a Java app in which i need to constantly check that if user is connected to internet or not. I'm doing this by constantly pinging a url and reading the response.
I want my app to work in following scenario 
Suppose when i started my app user was connected to internet but in between the internet connection is lost. I'm pining the url in a separate thread but the problem is if internet is disconnected in between the thread hangs and it doesn't gives an error that internet connection is lost. I'm using following code

```
p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping www.yahoo.com");

                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1
                .getInputStream()));

                        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        input.close();
```

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user is connected to the internet? I'm sure there is a better way to accomplish that.

Comment: actually i'm programming a remote desktop app and for client part i need to check if user is connected to internet so that if user can connect to server or not.

Comment: Just connect to the server and see if there are any errors. Pinging yahoo.com is not very reliable. It will give you both false negatives and positives.

Comment: Try "nslookup www.yahoo.com" instead of "ping www.yahoo.com" and see if that hangs up when the internet is not connected.  Better yet, user your own server address instead of Yahoo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't call an external program to do that :

```
InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName("www.yahoo.com");
boolean ok = inet.isReachable(timeout);
```

Comment: can you suggest me how much timeout will be suitable for my need?

Comment: At least 200 (it's in millisecondes). If your network may be very slow, simply put 1000 (one second). In any case, if you have a good network, the function will return true without waiting.

Comment: In your case, it could be more to the point to test directly with the name of your server instead of "www.yahoo.com".

Comment: Keep in mind that, if there is no internet connection `InetAddress.getByName` might also fail. I'm not sure, if there is a way to set this timeout.

Comment: @dystro i set the timeout to 1000 as you suggested but the problem is that it sometimes giving false negative. What can i do?

Comment: Does it work better with a greater timeout ? You could attempt this call regularly but in a normal network this should always work.